# What should be the type of the regmap_read val pointer

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to use the regmap api for accessing an I2C device and it is totally unclear what the expected type is of the val pointer.

Cfr : int regmap_read(struct regmap *map, unsigned int reg, unsigned int *val)

The 2 options I see are (both are bad btw imho):

[1] It is really suppose to be a pointer to an unsigned int type and you have to use an intermediate variable when reading it.  Since you do not know what bitsize and unsigned int type will be, you can never be sure that it will hold 32 bits.

[2] It is suppose to be a pointer to a type that corresponds to what you passed in val_bits in the regmap_config (and you have to incorrectly recast that pointer to the type  to what to API expects to make it compilable).

The documentation is not helpful at all (surprise):

```
/**
...
* @val: Pointer to store read value
...
*/
```

Things like https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9378201/ seems to suggest that it is [1], 
but i see other drivers which i assume work that do [2] eg:

```
static inline int
ar1335_read_reg(struct ar1335_info *info, u16 addr, u16 *val)
{
    return regmap_read(info->regmap, addr, (unsigned int *) val);
}
```

(https://github.com/Bogdacutu/STLinux-Kernel/blob/master/drivers/media/platform/tegra/ar1335.c)

If i try to follow the functions that (i think, it is full abstractions and more abstractions) are actually assigned to the read i think i end up at

```
static int regmap_i2c_read(void *context,
                       const void *reg, size_t reg_size,
                       void *val, size_t val_size)
{
    struct device *dev = context;
    struct i2c_client *i2c = to_i2c_client(dev);
    struct i2c_msg xfer[2];
    int ret;

    xfer[0].addr = i2c->addr;
    xfer[0].flags = 0;
    xfer[0].len = reg_size;
    xfer[0].buf = (void *)reg;

    xfer[1].addr = i2c->addr;
    xfer[1].flags = I2C_M_RD;
    xfer[1].len = val_size;
    xfer[1].buf = val;

    ret = i2c_transfer(i2c->adapter, xfer, 2);
    if (ret == 2)
            return 0;
    else if (ret < 0)
            return ret;
    else
            return -EIO;
}
```

which would suggest that it has to be a pointer to the real data type, so eg u16 * in case val_bits = 16.

Anyone any insights ?
If it is [2] why not use a void * pointer to avoid the ugly casts like in the i2c read ? Historical mess ?

Thanks,

Bram

Comment: It should be a pointer to type that have enough capacity to keep an unsigned int.

Comment: By the way, can you find similar examples (`ar1335.c::read_reg()`) in upstream kernel?

Comment: I checked a few cases with 8 or 16 bit val_bits settings, and they all seem to follow [1], so using an intermediate unsigned int value. 
Eg:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/iio/light/isl29018.c#L644   (8bit)
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/soc/codecs/wm8904.c?v=3.14            (16bit)

So maybe the ar1335 is just wrong then .... ?
(i still think it is a bad idea to use unsigned int instead of uint32/uint64 as a type in this API though)

Comment: Anyway as soon as my driver shows signs of life :) i will check empirically.

Comment: Better just to think about a bit more. And think why it's done this way in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all registers on AR1335 are 16bit aka uint16, according to [AR1335 Register Reference](https://community.nxp.com/pwmxy87654/attachments/pwmxy87654/imxrt/13464/4/AND9236-D%20%28AR1335%20RR%29.pdf)